# Can someone explain what these router options mean? and what to choose?

Tags: networking, router

I want to block or filter MAC Address but when i went to the router web based page settings i came to lots of options and choices that i don't understand or know which to select.
***router specifications*** are (**Type**: ZTE, **Model**: ZXHIN H108N). 
And ***the drop down lists options*** are like this;
(**Mode**:
Discard or permit.
**Type**: 
Bridge, Route, Bridge + Route.
**Protocol**:
IP, ARP, RARP, PPPoE, ALL).

here is an image

[image]

Comment: In the future, please use a more descriptive title.

Comment: I seem to have the same router, did find a way to block people?

Answer (score 2):

As it says, if you enable this with the "permit" option, it will turn into a whitelist, thus you must add your PC first so you still have access.

If you choose "discard" it will turn into a blacklist.

Answer (score 0):

you go to network -> WLAN -> Access control list.
first add all the mac addresses and then select "Permit" in the mode.